# Login Screen for multiple users AS3 Flash CS4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to have a login screen in the middle of my program. For a first time user, I want them to create a username that will be saved onto the computer locally.

When the user comes back to the program, I want them to login with their username and for the program to remember where that user left off in the program.

How would I be able to do this? And what if they have to go back to a section in a different scene?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a login system. To make such a system you must answer yourself following question:

- Are the login/passwords stored locally or on a remote server?
- Is your program a web application or a desktop application? Or both?

There are other questions, but let's not go so advanced right now.
When answering these questions you'll limit your choices, giving you a better vision of how the system should look like. Here are your choices for storing the login/pass chains:

- SharedObject, like cookies in a web-browser, but for the Flash player. They are stored locally on a users machine, so if the user changes a PC the pass/login will be lost.
- A locally saved file. Just like saving a password.txt file. You can do this only with a desktop application via AIR, otherwise you need to show a dialog to offer a user to save the password file in a desired location (not a good idea)
- A remotely accessed file/script that will give you the file with passwords to match or will validate the password itself and give you an answer.

Then you just need to make a login screen. There are unlimited number of ways to do all that. Let's just take a simple one:

- Make a class, something like LoginScreen.as
- Make a static function, something like showLoginForm()
- When calling the method put an overlay Sprite over the screen and on top of the overlay add the login form. That will disable other inputs by a mouse, you'll need to disable focusing object by pressing the Tab key yourself.
- After the login/pass were entered you can validate the chain an either close the login form (make a static function for that too) or show an error.

About remembering the state of the program:

You best study and use the MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern combination. There are tons of frameworks that uses MVC or MVCS (S for Services). I recommend Robotlegs (http://www.robotlegs.org). When the state of the application changes the model will hold the state. Save the model (SharedObject, in a file, send each model's change to a script) and then load it to resume your app from the point you've left it.